# Typescript: Infer type by passing function parameter to a Interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have this interface for example:

```
interface MyInterface {
    a: Something;
    b: SomethingElse;
}
```

And let's say I call the following:

```
const object: MyInterface = {
    a: {...},
    b: {...},
}
const getValue = (key: keyof MyInterface) => {
    const value: MyInterface[typeof key] = object[key];
    return value;
}

const value = getValue('a');
```

What I end up having is `value: Something | SomethingElse` instead of having `value: Something`. Of course, this is a pseudo-example, in reality I'm parsing some data from the vuex getter inside a composable, but does anyone have a clear answer to this? Thank you.

I've tried accessing the interface by getting `Interface[typeof key]`

Comment: Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N723rw)? Let me know if I should write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `getValue` function is manually set to `MyInterface[typeof key]`. But even without this manual type, TypeScript infers it to be `typeof object[key]`, i.e. `MyInterface[keyof MyInterface]`, which is exactly the same, since `typeof key` is `keyof MyInterface`.

`MyInterface[keyof MyInterface]` is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), which produces a union of all property types accessed by the indexing type, here `keyof MyInterface`. As described in patrickhrastnik's answer, the latter is itself a union of all keys of `MyInterface`, i.e. `'a' | 'b'`. And `MyInterface['a' | 'b']` is `Something | SomethingElse`.

TypeScript performs only static type analysis, therefore this is the best it can conclude when all it knows is that the `key` function parameter type is `keyof MyInterface`.

Hence to get a narrower return type, we have to *restrict* the type of `key`. Obviously, we still want to be able to call `getValue` function with any key of `MyInterface`, however.

A classic solution leverages [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function argument [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) to have TS guess the type of `key` parameter *where the function is called*; there, it can infer it as a more specific type, instead of all the `keyof` union. And we can still accept any of these keys as possible argument type by properly [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) the generic parameter type:

```
const getValue2 = <T extends keyof MyInterface>(key: T) => {
    //^? (key: T) => MyInterface[T]
    const value = object[key];
    return value;
}
```

With this function using generics, TypeScript can infer a more specific return type for each call:

```
const value2 = getValue2('a');
//    ^? Something

const value2b = getValue2('b');
//    ^? SomethingElse
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwsAFgSwHYHMoF4oDeUAzgFwnABOmOAvgNwBQoksiy62AogDbHT4i-chgCuCAEYRKUBo0aZg0gGYBDAMbQAsiACSGJZTWbCjKOairy8JKhpMLUCdfZ3ufCE1rz1cDMWAoOAkAKwh1YHIdfUNjAVNHK0IScgAiFggbDhpU2QAaMwtnZOEoAEZ8xm9ff0CsZAA1VR5ReIAKAGsIEHIukDhlKGiDFQ0IAEo8AD4EiwB6OYA9AH5C8xqAqAA3Zta5gCoovRGjMYBtDIGoPoBdfbm8INDw4DPbh3mHixW1qEpkUSUDDbXaeKo+PybHYteL1YBNGFtADkqiR4yYC0cP0YC1xePxBMJ+IhtSgcIRrQATI8ADwAFSgEAAHkoMAATYjXbpXYaxMZTTrdch0ya4GYEX4LH6ODaBaGtR7BMIRN7dG4fcz-YCA4HysHeRiykEw6n4cmgynI1HonFfczYo16ykSR7mk3IiRojF2qA-IA)

Comment: Hey man, can you please check one more issue? Instead of raising another question I thought to drop by here. Here's the link, I hope it will be straightforward [link](https://tsplay.dev/mpQnBW)

Comment: Hi, seems to me complex and different enough from the OP that it is absolutely worth a separate question. Please make sure to explain there your new situation in detail.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html

> The keyof operator takes an object type and produces a string or numeric literal union of its keys.

In this example, it makes sense that the `keyof` operand combines the subfields of `MyInterface` to result in `Something | SomethingElse`. It is - as far as I understand - what the documentation states the operand does.

I have no experience with the `keyof`, but to me this seems to do what it is designed for.